# Extract/read React propTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to visually test React components. The user can alter the component's props using a form. I would like to be able (for example) to render a `<select>` based on `React.PropTypes.oneOf(['green', 'blue', 'yellow'])`.

When I read `MyComponent.propTypes` it returnes a function defined by React. Is there a way to extract/read the prop types?

Comment: It would also be really interesting to programatically be able to read the default props using maybe `getDefaultProps` function.

Comment: Actually it is possible: axe-prop-types — https://www.npmjs.com/package/axe-prop-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't read directly from `propTypes` since, as you said, they are defined as functions.

You could instead define your propTypes in an intermediary format, from which you'd generate your `propTypes` static.

```js
var myPropTypes = {
  color: {
    type: 'oneOf',
    value: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  },
};

function processPropTypes(propTypes) {
  var output = {};
  for (var key in propTypes) {
    if (propTypes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // Note that this does not support nested propTypes validation
      // (arrayOf, objectOf, oneOfType and shape)
      // You'd have to create special cases for those
      output[key] = React.PropTypes[propTypes[key].type](propTypes[key].value);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: processPropTypes(myPropTypes),

  static: {
    myPropTypes: myPropTypes,
  },
});
```

You could then access your custom propTypes format via `MyComponent.myPropTypes` or `element.type.myPropTypes`.

Here's a helper to make this process a little easier.

```js
function applyPropTypes(myPropTypes, Component) {
  Component.propTypes = processPropTypes(myPropTypes);
  Component.myPropTypes = propTypes;
}

applyPropTypes(myPropTypes, MyComponent);
```

Comment: I was hoping that intermediary step was not necessary, but alas, it's clear, easy and maintainable, so why not... Thank you.

Comment: I wish there was a better way. We actually thought about one in my team and we'll try it. I'll give a feedback here if it's better.

Comment: @Vadorequest could you come up with a solution?

Comment: @DanLee Nope. Applying Alexandre's solution was too much time consumming at the time, so I just forgot about it. But IMO it's the closest solution, what I don't like is the necessity to update all the components using the new way. I wished React would provide something at some point.

Comment: @Vadorequest Alright, I expected that there isn't an easy solution. Thanks a bunch! But it makes sense, as the PropTypes are stripped away in production anyway. We would've use it to make our components more descriptive like in `react-storybook`.

Comment: you can use npmjs.com/package/axe-prop-types

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding a code example of what you are trying to do as I don't quite understand but why are you accessing propTypes? PropTypes don't contain values but rather expectations of what your value types should be for the different props passed into the component.

If you have a form that lets you alter the props I assume you are passing in the prop into the component that will be rendering the select component.You can access these props through props object.

If you are trying to validate the propTypes that can have the form of different types the following can be used:

```
optionalUnion: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
  React.PropTypes.string,
  React.PropTypes.number,
  React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Message)
])
```

Comment: He wants to display the defined `propTypes` of a React Component dynamically in order to display the properties of the component to an end-user. I actually want to do the same, for documentation purpose.

Comment: Exactly! Haven't looked into this recently or researched it further though.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axe-prop-types this will allow you to extract all prop-types